# Python csv column names from rows and assign to columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I bet there is a simple way to do this but I can't figure it out. I have a series of data from various races. The problem is that all the data is combined and there are different lap distances and times. What I'd like to do is dynamically input data into columns for each race. Here's how gross the data can be

- 200m -    18.70 - (18.7)|600m -    47.50 - (28.8)|1000m -  1:16.62 - (29.1)|1400m -  1:45.74 - (29.1)|1800m -  2:14.95 - (29.2)|2200m -  2:44.16 - (29.2)|2600m -  3:13.27 - (29.1)|3000m -  3:42.40 - (29.1)|3400m -  4:11.70 - (29.3)|3800m -  4:41.11 - (29.4)|4200m -  5:10.75 - (29.6)|4600m -  5:40.39 - (29.6)|5000m -  6:10.44 - (30.0)|
- 600m -    45.92 - (27.7)|1000m -  1:16.24 - (30.3)|
- 300m -    23.51 - (23.5)|700m -    48.80 - (25.2)|1100m -  1:14.96 - (26.1)|1500m -  1:42.48 - (27.5)|

I know all the columns that are possible and there are 42. What I'd like is if the row data has the same value as the column to grab the time from that data. And if not to put nothing in that columns spot. For example the first one would put 18.70-(18.7) in the 200m column, a null in the 300m column and a 47.50 - (28.8) in the 600m column etc...  Ultimately creating a sparse csv file from this in the end.

Any ideas?

Comment: While on the train, I hacke another answer at your disposal, which only uses builtin functionality ;-) HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution below. A couple notes:

1. I used [tablib](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/), my favorite library for things like CSV manipulation, and [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) to sort the columns ("300m" < "2000m").
2. I discovered the set of headers by taking the union of all the races available in each row of the data. You could instead just hardcode that list, since you said you know all the possible values there.
3. The map/strip/partition line is probably confusing... the partition call splits on the first `" - "`, returning `(first_part, " - ", second_part)`. The `[::2]` just throws away the `" - "` for me. Then I strip whitespace from the remaining parts.

Otherwise, hopefully the code is self-explanatory:

```
from natsort import natsorted
import tablib

data = '''200m - 18.70 - (18.7)|600m - 47.50 - (28.8)|1000m - 1:16.62 - (29.1)|1400m - 1:45.74 - (29.1)|1800m - 2:14.95 - (29.2)|2200m - 2:44.16 - (29.2)|2600m - 3:13.27 - (29.1)|3000m - 3:42.40 - (29.1)|3400m - 4:11.70 - (29.3)|3800m - 4:41.11 - (29.4)|4200m - 5:10.75 - (29.6)|4600m - 5:40.39 - (29.6)|5000m - 6:10.44 - (30.0)|
600m - 45.92 - (27.7)|1000m - 1:16.24 - (30.3)|
300m - 23.51 - (23.5)|700m - 48.80 - (25.2)|1100m - 1:14.96 - (26.1)|1500m - 1:42.48 - (27.5)|'''

dictionaries = []
headers = set()

for row in data.split('\n'):
    row_dict = {}
    for entry in row.split('|'):
        column, value = map(str.strip, entry.partition(' - ')[::2])
        if column:
            row_dict[column] = value
    dictionaries.append(row_dict)
    headers.update(row_dict.keys())

headers = natsorted(headers)
dataset = tablib.Dataset(headers=headers)
for row_dict in dictionaries:
    dataset.append([row_dict.get(header) for header in headers])

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(dataset.csv)
```

Output:

```
200m,300m,600m,700m,1000m,1100m,1400m,1500m,1800m,2200m,2600m,3000m,3400m,3800m,4200m,4600m,5000m
18.70 - (18.7),,47.50 - (28.8),,1:16.62 - (29.1),,1:45.74 - (29.1),,2:14.95 - (29.2),2:44.16 - (29.2),3:13.27 - (29.1),3:42.40 - (29.1),4:11.70 - (29.3),4:41.11 - (29.4),5:10.75 - (29.6),5:40.39 - (29.6),6:10.44 - (30.0)
,,45.92 - (27.7),,1:16.24 - (30.3),,,,,,,,,,,,
,23.51 - (23.5),,48.80 - (25.2),,1:14.96 - (26.1),,1:42.48 - (27.5),,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: This is fantastic! exactly what I was looking for. I had other data problems but once I cleared those up I think I have this working exactly as it should... Except that dataset.csv when I go to write it to file it gives me two new lines for every row, is there a simple solution for that too?

Comment: Hmm, I don't seem to have that problem? Maybe share the actual data you're working with?

Comment: Oh, see my edit and give that a try. I switched it to explicitly write out a file in binary mode rather than just print the data to the console. The tablib docs explain why: http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=windows#tablib.Dataset.csv. (I'm assuming you're on Windows.)

Answer (score 0):

While off the internet I also took a stab a the specification that "sat in the question" ;-)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
"""Learn by example - grass roots parser for kind of serialized
race reports, where records are separated by a pipe (|), fields
of result records separated y a dash (-) and some meaning is associated
with the fields per position in record."""
from __future__ import print_function


def parse_duration_string(text, min_sep=':'):
    """Simplistic parser, splitting duration sof minutes:seconds.fract
    into an ordered numerical pair of (integer, float). The minute portion
    is set to 0 if no min_sep is detected."""

    s_text = text.strip()
    minutes = 0
    if min_sep in s_text:
        min_cand, sec_cand = s_text.split(min_sep)
        minutes = int(min_cand)
        seconds = float(sec_cand)
    else:
        seconds = float(s_text)

    return minutes, seconds


def parse_sports_concat(text, token_set, rec_sep='|', field_sep='-'):
    """Split parse the text per record separator rec_sep,
    token in token_ser and subsequently split parse the associated
    result serialization (by field_sep) and use Occams razor
    against the noise ;-)."""

    shave_these = '( )'
    race_map = {}
    for record in text.split(rec_sep):
        s_record = record.strip()
        if not s_record:
            continue
        dist, in_secs, magic = s_record.split(field_sep)
        key = dist.strip()
        if key in token_set:
            if key not in race_map:
                race_map[key] = []
            race_map[key].append(
                (parse_duration_string(in_secs), magic.strip(shave_these)))
        else:
            print("Warning: Distance({0}) not found in TokenSet!".format(key))
    return race_map


def main():
    """Test drive the split, parse, map."""

    line_seq = (
        ('200m - 18.70 - (18.7)|600m - 47.50 - (28.8)|'
         '1000m - 1:16.62 - (29.1)|1400m - 1:45.74 - (29.1)|'
         '1800m - 2:14.95 - (29.2)|2200m - 2:44.16 - (29.2)|'
         '2600m - 3:13.27 - (29.1)|3000m - 3:42.40 - (29.1)|'
         '3400m - 4:11.70 - (29.3)|3800m - 4:41.11 - (29.4)|'
         '4200m - 5:10.75 - (29.6)|4600m - 5:40.39 - (29.6)|'
         '5000m - 6:10.44 - (30.0)|'),
        '600m - 45.92 - (27.7)|1000m - 1:16.24 - (30.3)|',
        ('300m - 23.51 - (23.5)|700m - 48.80 - (25.2)|'
         '1100m - 1:14.96 - (26.1)|1500m - 1:42.48 - (27.5)|'),
    )
    core_seq = (
        1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 18, 22, 26,
        30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50)
    token_seq = tuple('%dm' % (z * 100,) for z in core_seq)
    total_map = {}
    for line in line_seq:
        total_map.update(parse_sports_concat(line, set(token_seq)))

    for distance in token_seq:
        print('{0}: {1}'.format(distance,
                                total_map.get(distance, 'NotReported')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

yields:

```
100m: NotReported
200m: [((0, 18.7), '18.7')]
300m: [((0, 23.51), '23.5')]
300m: [((0, 23.51), '23.5')]
600m: [((0, 45.92), '27.7')]
700m: [((0, 48.8), '25.2')]
1000m: [((1, 16.24), '30.3')]
1100m: [((1, 14.96), '26.1')]
1400m: [((1, 45.74), '29.1')]
1500m: [((1, 42.48), '27.5')]
1800m: [((2, 14.95), '29.2')]
2200m: [((2, 44.16), '29.2')]
2600m: [((3, 13.27), '29.1')]
3000m: [((3, 42.4), '29.1')]
3400m: [((4, 11.7), '29.3')]
3800m: [((4, 41.11), '29.4')]
4200m: [((5, 10.75), '29.6')]
4600m: [((5, 40.39), '29.6')]
5000m: [((6, 10.44), '30.0')]
```

It parses with only build in methods from the strings provided a parsed map, extends it by updates merged over multiple lines and also parses the time into a pair of integer minutes and float seconds. The third filedcalle dmagic is left as is, but stripped from the parentheses, as this is nowsafely stored in a fixed "slot".

Note, that the variable `in_secs`might be not so good a name, but who knows.

You can easily leave the duration strings as they are by not calling the parseduration_string() function.

Enjoy the Python learning journey - above code snippets are compliant with PEP8 and this is often helpful in Python land to get to know this PEP8 and pythonic patterns / idioms, and profit from the unified read of code that helps others jump right into the problem zones.

PS: The insert with prior test of existence of a distance found into the race_map is a bit clumsy, but explicit - especially when beginning to learn a laguage - is better than implicit, I guess.